# Input validator function does not accept valid input

Tags: python

The following function asks for a user input until it receives an input of `1` or `2`. I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution that does not involve the try/except statement or recursion.

```
def input_params(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(prompt))
            if user_input == 1 or user_input == 2:
                return user_input
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")
                input_params(prompt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: The worst part of this code is you are combining recursion and a loop, *and* you aren't returning the return value of the recursive call. Fix that, and then you can worry about whether you are handling potential `ValueError`s from the call to `int` properly.

Comment: Why is `x` a parameter to the function in the first place, when you immediately replace it with user input?

Comment: How exactly would you fix that?, would you say ```return x, y``` after the ```inputParams()``` recursion?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the purpose of the function simply to prompt the user for input until they enter `1` or `2`?

Comment: @chepner, this code is part of a bigger piece, which requires an x param to work, i believe you are able to ignore it for any solutions

Comment: @chepner, yes that is what I wish to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking it as list `[1,2]`. I have done with : `if int(x) == 1 or int(x) == 2:`

**Code :**

```
def userInput():
    while True:
        x = input("Enter value : ")

        if x.isnumeric() :
            if int(x) == 1 or int(x) == 2:
                return x
        else:
            print('Not Number')

userInput()
```

Feel free to correct me if anything wrong in above code

Comment: Hey, this is amazing, this completely removes the ValueError and is very short and readable, perhaps instead of x.isnumeric, one code ignore the whole ```int(x)``` part, and simply ask ```if x == "1" or x == "2", else: print("Invalid Input")```This I feel simplifies it further, as I am not familiar with .isnumeric(). We could also simply ```return int(x)``` if the input that needs to be processed needs to be an int

Comment: @PythonProgrammer : Thanks for your valuable input you can make edit will approve it

Answer (score 2):

Skip the recursion, and use the `ValueError` to continue the loop before checking the integer value.

```
def inputParam(prompt):
    while True:
        x = input(prompt)
        try:
            n = int(x)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer input")
            continue

        if n == 1 or n == 2:
            return n

        print("Enter 1 or 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
def inputParams(prompt):
    while True:
        x = input(prompt)
        if x.isnumeric():
            x = int(x)
            if x in [1, 2]:
                return x
            else:
                print("Invalid input!")
        else:
            print("please input only number")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid try-except block entirely, you can use the following code. It's not common to use `contextlib.suppress` but in this isolated situation, it can work out nicely.

```py
import contextlib

def inputParams(prompt):
    while True:
        with contextlib.suppress(ValueError):
            if (x := int(input(prompt))) in [1, 2]:
                return x
        print("Invalid input, try again.")

print(f"You entered {inputParams('Enter 1 or 2: ')}.")
```

Comment: This is quite confusing to me, but it works. Will definitely check out contextlib documentation as the value error factor is just completely eliminated!